# Android project assets consume enormous amount of space in Git repo

Tags: android, git, github, bitbucket, git-lfs

In my Android project, I have a lot of heavy binary assets under `<project>/src/main/assets`. There's numerous files that collectively add up to tens, maybe hundreds of megabytes. Git LFS might not be an option here due to the number of files, but I'm not sure. What would be everyone's recommendation to keep these files out of Git to keep main repository size small? This becomes especially important when hosting git repositories on cloud services like Bitbucket and Github.

Comment: Are you going to be updating or rebuilding these files in a commit-by-commit fashion, or will they remain relatively static as other things progress?

Comment: You can have your heavy assets binaries as a separate repository and load them into your project by implementing git submodules. It will checkout the binaries for your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open-source [project](http://git-lfs.github.com/) aimed at handling large files in .git. It is pretty popular and should help you in your case.